# How to handle brackets in JSON array sent to Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services, asp.net-ajax

I have a web service which just catches inbound data.  If the incoming data is a stringified JSON array, the sever returns a 500 level error:

```
ExceptionType : "System.InvalidOperationException"
Message: "Type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' is not supported for deserialization of an array."
at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertListToObject(IList list, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, IList& convertedList)
.........
```

I did some testing and it has to do with the brackets in the stringified JSON array.  Sending stringified JSON objects (just curly braces) causes no errors.  I.e. `"{"id":111,"val":"x"}"` versus `"[{"id":111,"val":"x"}]"`

What confuses me is, I'm not doing any deserialization in the web method. 
 It's all happening upstream before I can access the request.  The web method is below:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod]
public void CatchData()
{
    HttpRequest inboundRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;

    System.IO.Stream stream = inboundRequest.InputStream;
    stream.Position = 0;
    string contents = "";
    using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

}
```

Two questions:

What do I need to change so that the web method can handle the brackets in the stringified JSON?

What exactly is going on here?  It took me a while to realize that HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream is being used by something upstream of the web method, and so to re-read its contents, I need to set its position to 0.  What's happening upstream when content type is set to application/json?  If you set content type to application/text, there is no need to reset the stream.

Comment: Sounds like the type your expecting is an array but your strigifying a single object when there is only 1 object in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You obviously have a handler configured in your upstream that is reading the request. I'd imagine either webmethod or scriptmethod is adding the handler, though if you're in a complex project an httphandler may be in play. Without knowing more about your entire solution, a better answer is impossible.

If you simply want to handle any raw input yourself, build and register an httphandler.